# Kannada font not rendering after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: fonts

After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, Kannada text is appearing as boxes. In 14.04 they used to rendered correctly. How to correct it?

google home page screenshot (Kannada and Telugu text appearing as boxes):

[image]